# Do not close ontap inside tooltip

Tags: flutter, tooltip

How to have interactions inside a tooltip?

By default, as soon as you tap inside, it closes the toolip, except I would like to have clickable links for example:

```
Tooltip(
    height: 50,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80),
    richMessage: makeTooltip(context, issuerAddress, issuerName),
    child: Text('Hover me'));

InlineSpan makeTooltip(BuildContext context, String address, String name) {
    return WidgetSpan(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: address));
            },
            child: Text(
              address,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          Text(name),
        ]),
    );
  }
```

Currently `GestureDetector` does not work, tooltip closes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the GestureDetector with a Material? I'm assuming you want the tooltip to be dismissible as well.

```
          child: Column(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: address));
                },
                child: Material(
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text(
                      address,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              Text(name),
            ]),
        );
```

Comment: No this doesn't change anything

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).